# Proof of set closer and more

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups

So this is a topological question I got on my exam some time ago
" For $A \subset X$ and $ \epsilon \gt 0 $ let $$B(A, \epsilon) = {x \in X : \underset{a \in A}{\exists}d(x,a)\lt \epsilon}$$
-Prove thet $B(A,\epsilon)$ is an open set

-Prove then $\overline{A} = \bigcap^\infty_{n=1} B(A, \frac{1}{n})$"

Obviously I wasn't able to do it, hence I'm posing it here in hope thet someone will shed some light on this question

Answer (score 1):

Hint for first part: If $x \in B(A,\epsilon)$ then there exists $a \in A$ such that $d(x,a)<\epsilon$. Show that $B(x, \frac {\epsilon -d(x,a)} 2) \subseteq B(A,\epsilon)$.

Hint for second part: $\overline {A}=\{x: d(x,A)=0\}=\cap_n \{x: d(x,A) <\frac 1   n\}$.

Comment: I did the first part, but I still don't really understand how to do the second part, could you elaborate?

Comment: @WPHakoon If $x \in \overline {A}$ there exists $a_k \in A$ such that $a_k \to a$. Hence $d(x,A) \leq d(x,a_k) <\frac 1 n$ if $k$ is chosen large enough. Conversely if $d(x,A) <\frac 1 n$ for all $n$ then (by definition of $d(x,A)$)  there exists $a_n \in $ such that $d(x,a_n) <\frac 1 n$. Since $a_n \to a$ we get $a \in \overline {A}$.